# Using json file stored data in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am attempting to use data from a json file which has information stored by the user. But when I print from it, it displays all the information stored in it. How do I extract only 1 part? Here is the code:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["shib, shibaku, Shib"])
async def Shibaku(ctx, int = 0):

  if int == 1:
    with open('Shibaku1.json') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
      for oslink in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
        await ctx.send(oslink)
```

Here is the code for storing information in "Shibaku1.json"

```py
@client.command()
async def shibaku1(ctx, coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6, shibakunumber, oslink):
  await ctx.message.delete()

  with open('Shibaku10.json', 'r') as f:
    coins_data = json.load(f)
  coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)] = (coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6, shibakunumber, oslink)
  with open('Shibaku10.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(coins_data, f)
```

Sameple json file:

```
{"331971067788787733": ["\ud83d\ude04", "\ud83d\ude06", "\ud83d\ude00", "\ud83d\ude01", "\ud83d\ude05", "\ud83e\udd0f", "1", "1"]
```

I want to display only the "oslink" part.

Comment: I use dictionaries in my json, extract all of it, then call the dictionaries, which gives me only the values for that dictionary.

Comment: I don't know what to write in the code in order to call only one of the values, how would that work? @EpicEfeathers

Comment: can u just add a sample json file , like how it looks and when u send oslink what does it send

Comment: @gim have your json file look like this: 
```{dict1: WhatYouWantToCall}, {dict2: WhateverYouWant}```
Then pull the json and call dict1, if you want its information.

Comment: @DjWalkzz I edited the post and added the sample json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["shib, shibaku, Shib"])
async def Shibaku(ctx, int = 0):

  if int == 1:
    with open('Shibaku1.json') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
      for oslink in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
        await ctx.send(oslink)
```

In this `for` loop block, you are iterating every single element of the value of `coins_data[author_id]`.
And from what I can tell, your `coins_data` is structured like:

```
{
    author_id1: (list of coins, shibakunumber, oslink),
    author_id2: (list of coins, shibakunumber, oslink),
    ...
}
```

Because the value for key of `author_id` is only a list, you are sending all of coins, shibakunumber, *and* the oslink.

If you only want to send the oslink, you need to structure the data so that you can specifically call for the oslink.
For example, a nested dictionaries will work:

```
{
    author_id1: {
        coin1: value,
        coin2: value, 
        ..., 
        oslink: somevalue
    },
    author_id2: {
        coin1: value,
        coin2: value, 
        ..., 
        oslink: somevalue
    },
    ...
}
```

This way, you can specifically look for it like `coins_data[str(stx.author.id)]["oslink"]`

Comment: So how would I store the? Bit confused on how the code would work @shark

Answer (score 0):

so u want every coin come 1 by 1 , so heres my answer :

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["shib, shibaku, Shib"])
async def Shibaku(ctx, int = 0):

  if int == 1:
    with open('Shibaku1.json') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
      user_coin_list = coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]
      for oslink in user_coin_list:
        await ctx.send(oslink)
```

so above works like when u get `coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]` it returns list and then u have to run for loop in list but u were running for loop in json.